# Can I stop a format disc operation midway?

Tags: hard-drive, security, filesystems, format

I'm formating a new HDD (Toshiba 1TB from NTFS to FAT32) to fit it on my old PS3. But it's taking a lifetime to get the thing done...
Meanwhile I found on the internet some tutorials using other ways to change the file system in a nick of time (maxtor maxblast [http://youtu.be/At7MkMFWHA0] and a GUI format app I found in ridgecrop consultants [http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm])

Can I stop the process and try it the way they explain it with messing up the new drive?

Comment: Can you stop the process;  Sure;  Will those tools be any faster I very much doubt it.  A 1TB quick format should only take about 20 seconds at most.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the currently in-progress formatting session but this will leave the entire drive unformatted. If you start formatting the drive after this then it will start formating from the beginning.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, at least _my_ question, of _how_ to stop the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can. The drive will be unformatted.

IMHO the quickest way of getting it done is by means of GParted Live (http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Just create a new MBR, a new partition of the FAT32 type and click apply changes. It should be done in seconds or a couple of minutes at most.

Comment: This is the best way to go. Rather than formatting the drive, just make the new partition table. GParted is perfect for this.

But be warned, this is not going to erase any data on the drive, and neither would a regular Windows format. To do that, you'll have to zero the drive out, which could take hours depending on how fast your processor is and how fast the drive's write speed is.

Comment: Downvoting relevant answers, for not being "useful"? People spend time on trying to answer and get that? I begin to dislike that a lot.

Comment: Secure erase is more than doing a full format - read http://www.microsoft.com/security/online-privacy/safely-dispose-computers-and-devices.aspx